# Why I cannot connect to remote database when using tablediff.exe?

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

I am trying to sync to tables on differenet servers (Local one and remote one) using this code that  I rum from the command prompt:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\COM\tablediff.exe" -sourceserver localpc\SQL2014 -sourcedatabase localdb -sourceschema sche -sourcetable table1 -destinationserver remotepc\SQLEXPRESS -destinationdatabase remotedb -destinationschema sche -destinationtable table1 -et Difference -f d:\table1_differences.sql
```

but I recieve the error : unable to access database remotedb

The local db is SQL server 2014 express edition
The remote db is SQL server 2014 express edition
Firewall is turned off.
I assigned the admin user as the logon account for the sql service on the remote server.

**NOTE** I can connect to the remote db normally from C# application or from my local SQL server .
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by assigning the -destinationuser and -destinationpassword parameters